# How to state a lemma about equiv in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to learn Isabelle notation and syntax from its documentation. In particular, I am trying to state a lemma using the equivalence notation (`equiv` in main.pdf of Isabelle 2020).

```
equiv  :: 'a set ⇒ ('a × 'a) set ⇒ bool
```

The lemma does not have to be useful, but I was hoping to get the grammar right. I tried to fill the blanks with something as follows, hoping to state that equality is an equivalence relation:

```
lemma "equiv nat (=)"
```

The attempt wasn't successful and generates this error:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "_ set"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  equiv :: ??'a set ⇒ (??'a × ??'a) set ⇒ bool
Operand:   nat :: int ⇒ nat
```

My questions are:

*How to state the equivalence about equality correctly?*

*More generally, how does one go about discovering the right way to use the basic notation or syntax such as those in Main?*

(I am interested in notation only here, not necessarily proving anything)

Comment: short answer: nat is the conversion from int to nat. You need `UNIV::nat set` (if you have the right imports); Equality is curried. You need to uncurry it.

Answer (score 1):

The first critical thing when trying notations is to look at types or type error messages:

```
Operator:  equiv :: ??'a set ⇒ (??'a × ??'a) set ⇒ bool
Operand:   nat :: int ⇒ nat
```

shows that `nat` has type `int ⇒ nat`, while `equiv` expects the first argument to have type `?'a set`. So you somehow want a set of natural numbers, instead of the function that converts an integer to a natural number.

How to fix that problem? Either you already know that `UNIV` exists for such purpose or you search for example on [Find facts](https://search.isabelle.in.tum.de/#search/default_Isabelle2020_AFP2020?q=%7B%22term%22%3A%22nats%22%2C%22facets%22%3A%7B%22Kind%22%3A%5B%22Constant%22%5D%7D%7D), based on some intuition on the name.

Once you have changed that, you will see a similar typing problem for equality that you can easily fix.